# SQL troubling with multiple count in query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I already provide sql fiddle with schema and sample data.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9d22/7/0

If I would like to know how many province and how many cities in Thailand.

```
Country Name | No. Provinces | No. Cities
  Thailand   |   77          |  1234
```

I guess that it need to use multiple COUNT(*) but I dont know how to use it.

Anybody know please suggest solution?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Query to Count() multiple tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379723/sql-query-to-count-multiple-tables)

Comment: Your sqlfiddle is for MySQL, while your question is tagged PostgreSQL. And @ithcy proposes an Oracle question as duplicate (which isn't a duplicate at all). Anybody needs some coffee maybe?!

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter haha, yes! I selected the wrong dupe. Unfortunately I can't rescind or re-cast my close vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `GROUP BY` and `COUNT`:

```
SELECT c.name, count(distinct p.id) provincecoutn, count(distinct city.id) citycount
FROM country c
  LEFT JOIN province p on c.id = p.country_id
  LEFT JOIN City on p.id = city.province_id
GROUP BY c.name
```

Good luck.

Comment: It is not right (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9d22/15/0)

No. of Province should be two.

Comment: @AtomSkaaskaHic -- Nope -- in your data, province only has 1 record for country id 1 :) The 2nd record is pointing at country id 2.  Make sense?

Comment: @AtomSkaaskaHic -- No worries, glad we could help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    C.Name, COUNT(DISTINCT P.Id) NoProvance, COUNT(CC.Id) NoCities
FROM country C
    JOIN province P
        ON C.Id = P.COUNTRY_ID
    JOIN city CC
        ON P.Id = CC.province_id
WHERE C.Name = 'Thailand'
GROUP BY C.Name
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9d22/16/0)**

Comment: I try your fiddle but it not right. No. of province should be 2 and cities should be 3.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably faster to count cities per province *before* joining to province:

```
SELECT c.name          AS "Country Name"
      ,count(p.id)     AS "No. Provinces"
      ,sum(ci.city_ct) AS "No. Cities" 
FROM   country       c
LEFT   JOIN province p ON p.country_id = c.id
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT province_id, count(*) AS city_ct FROM city GROUP BY 1
   ) ci ON ci.province_id = p.id
GROUP  BY 1
```

[-> sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/1ab81/1) for PostgreSQL(!)